# Managing List of objects using PrimeFaces 5

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have trouble "managing" List of objects using Primefaces 5.0.8.

I want to create "form" with functionality:

1. add new objects to list
2. remove objects from list
3. edit any object from the list

All functionality should be in one page without any dialogs. For list representation I am using primeface "dataTable" component. And I have problem to update/process only part of dataTable then remove button is clicked.

Simplified jsf view, I have come up with:

```
<p:dataGrid id="myObjectList"
            value="#{myManagedBean.myObjectList}"
            var="obj"   
            rowIndexVar="dataGridRowIndex"
            columns="1">


    <p:outputLabel value="row number: #{dataGridRowIndex}"/>
    <h:panelGrid id="parentGrid" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="property1" for="property1Input"/>
        <p:inputText id="property1Input" value="#{obj.property1}" required="true"/>   

        <p:outputLabel value="property2" for="property2Input"/>
        <p:inputText id="property2Input" value="#{obj.property2}"/>   
    </h:panelGrid> 

    <p:commandButton id="removeButton" 
                     icon="ui-icon-minus"
                     update="myObjectList"
                     process="@this"
                     actionListener="#{myManagedBean.myObjectList.remove(obj)}"
                     rendered="#{myManagedBean.myObjectList.size() &gt; 1}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="addButton" 
                     icon="ui-icon-plus"
                     update="myObjectList"
                     process="myObjectList"
                     actionListener="#{myManagedBean.addNewObjectToList()}"
                     rendered="#{myManagedBean.myObjectList.size() == dataGridRowIndex +1}"/> 
    <p:separator/>  
</p:dataGrid>
```

Simplified  managed bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Named
@Scope(value = "view")
public class MyManagedBean {

    private final List<MyObject> myObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject("test1"));
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject("test2"));
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject(""));
    }

    public void addNewObjectToList() {
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject());
    }

    public List<MyObject> getMyObjectList() {
        return myObjectList;
    }

}
```

And simplified “business” object:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;

    public MyObject() {
    }

    public MyObject(String property1) {
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    public void setProperty1(String property1) {
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }

    public void setProperty2(String property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

}
```

This code has one major problem:

If user enters some text to “property1Input” in first row and then clicks “removeButton” on second row, value entered to the first row disappears (because all “myObjectList” is updated and “removeButton” does not submit values)

I cannot submit values on “removeButton” because I do not want show validations/conversion errors then user clicks “removeButton” (“business” object in example are simplified).

I cannot add ‘immediate=”true” + ‘process=”myObjectList”’ for “removeButton” because of “removed” value “stays” input component, so if after “remove” user clicks “add” he will see removed value.

The only working workaround I found is on “removeButton” click not remove object from list, but hide row in dataTable, but this workaround requires lots of additional coding and looks really ugly.

So is there any other simple solution for this problem?